# Why a media library not shown in Wordpress and images are not uploaded into the media library?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Media library is not displayed neither I can upload nor I can see the uploaded media files. So  kindly help me out to this situation.

Comment: Please check folder permission first!!!! wp-content/uploads

Comment: As said, check files permission on your server first. If that's not the cause of your issue, you will get help only if you share more details about your installation configuration.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more understandable. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just by uploading files into the wp-content/uploads won't show up in the Media Library , those media ID's needs to be there in the database to show up in the Media Library.

If you already have files in the uploads folder and want to add them into the database, you can use this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) to add files from server.

But this is not the correct solution instead fix the permissions issue for that uploads folder.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is shown by following issue

1. Does your server have the **right permission** for upload file into upload folder check it.
2. don't upload file directly to upload folder upload it by backend which will not added media information to database.